# LoadXML with ":" in attributes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

I need to manipulate a XML string.
The string is this one :

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
```

I thought I would convert it into a XmlDocument, but `XmlDocument.LoadXml()` throws an error about the ":" character ; it's because of the `fb:like:layout` attribute.

What I need to do, is add an `addthis:url` attribute to the first element with a `addthis_toolbox` or `addthis_button` class.

I'm pretty confident that I can find the element with the correct class, but I'm not really confident that I can add a "composite" attribute like that... especially since I can't even load the thing to a XmlDocument.

Did I miss something ? Is there a better/simpler way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided XML isn't well-formed, so you can't manipulate it using XML parser.

You can perform pre-processing of this text, so it becomes well-formed XML, then manipulate it as XML using XML engine.

*EDIT*:

Read: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

But may be in your case usage of regex is most appropriate, if you structure of input HTML is regular, e.g.:

You can use this regex

```
(?x)
(?<=<)[^>]*
class="[^"]*
\b(?:addthis_toolbox|addthis_button)\b
[^"]*"
[^>]*
```

to find `div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style "`, then replace this string, i.e.:

```
string xml = @"<div class=""addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style "">
<a class=""addthis_button_facebook_like"" fb:like:layout=""button_count""></a>
<a class=""addthis_button_tweet""></a>
<a class=""addthis_counter addthis_pill_style""></a>
</div>
";

const string Pattern = @"(?xs)
    (?<=<)([^>]*
    class=""[^""]*
    \b(?:addthis_toolbox|addthis_button)\b
    [^""]*"")
    [^>]*
";

var result = Regex.Replace(xml, Pattern, "$0 addthis:url=\"value\"");
```

Result:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style " addthis:url="value">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: @cosmo0, Multiple colons are not allowed in XML name.

Comment: Ok... well, I can't change that, it's what AddThis gives me. What can I do, then ?

Comment: I mean, how can I transform it to well-formed XML ? I just can't remove the double-colons.

Comment: @cosmo0, you can just remove this string, and then load this XML in XmlDocument

Answer (score 5):

The XML is well-formed according to the XML 1.0 recommendation, but it is not namespace-well-formed according to the XML Namespaces 1.0 recommendation. So you should be able to parse it if your XML parser has a switch to disable namespace processing. I've no idea if .net's XmlDocument parser has such a switch.

Answer (score 1):

http://64.215.254.44/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=26854

> You can actually remove the following: fb:like:layout="button_count"
>   since button count is the default layout.